# Need to Execute Javascript in Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, eval

The following code works in Chrome and Firefox. But I'm having trouble with Safari.

Main.php contains:

```
<script>
function show<?php echo $s; ?>(str) {
if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("textOrder").innerHTML = "";

    return;
} else {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("textOrder").innerHTML =       this.responseText;

             $.post("<?php echo site_url(); ?>/test.php?q=" + str, function(response){




                   $("#ajax_responses").load(response);
$("#ajax_responses").html(response);

     var quantity = $('#quantity',response).val();
                     document.getElementById('example').value = quantity;

$("#ajax_responses").find("script")(function(){
 eval($(this).text());
 });
   });

         }
     };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/test.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

  }
}




</script>
<div id="ajax_responses" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I have Javascript inside of my AJAX response file that I'm trying to execute. The code executes in Chrome and Firefox.

My test.php contains the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="runscript">


    alert("test");

</script>
```

How can I get the Javascript to execute in Safari?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: any console errors to report?

Comment: this `$("#ajax_responses").load(response);
$("#ajax_responses").html(response);` looks completely suspect anyway - you sure you aren't getting errors in other browsers?

Comment: Hi, ` $("#ajax_responses").html(response) ` works fine in Chrome and Firefox. I haven't tested it with IE but I'm not concerned about that one. But I can't get Safari to work.

Comment: I checked in Safari this error appeared in the console 

[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'
 (anonymous function) (jquery.min.js, line 4)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (0.00<a, line 0)

Comment: `the server responded with a status of 404` - why would it do that only for suffery?

Comment: I'm not sure. I did check the console in Chrome and the same 404 error appears however the entire "test.php" is called successfully.

Comment: Is there any way to execute javascript from a Ajax call in Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really surprised no one provided any answers... However, I found a solution to the problem.

You can echo the javascript with PHP in the Ajax call.

Something like this:

```
 <?php echo '<script>alert("test")</script>'; ?>
```